# Why I still get object object error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript to update a php session variable :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#facebook_img').live('click',function(){
login_condetion = 1;                
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'facebook_login_condition_variable.php',
                data:{login_condetion:login_condetion},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(123);
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    /*alert(XMLHttpRequest);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);*/
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I print the session value before and after this code but it never change and when I alert responsText I get nothing and XMLHttpRequest gives me object object error .

This is my php code :

```
<?php 
$temp = $_POST['login_condetion'];
if(!empty($temp) && $temp != 0)
{
   $_SESSION['do_not_allow_auto_facebook_login'] = 1;
}
else    
{
    $_SESSION['do_not_allow_auto_facebook_login'] = 0;
}
$go = $_SESSION;
echo json_encode($go);
?>
```

Is there any problem with dataType of ajax function ? or it is a php session problem ? Please help me because I have been stuck here for long time.

Comment: `.live()` still using it, `.on()` is recommended.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but "condition" is correctly spelled in some code and in other code, misspelled "condetion"

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` in the top of your PHP file?

Comment: `object object` Is not an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions..

1. Do you start the `session` at top of the page where you use it.

   session_start();
2. in php code replace

   $go = $_SESSION;

with

```
 $go = $_SESSION['do_not_allow_auto_facebook_login'];
```

3.Do you need the datatype `json`, if not remove this line

```
echo json_encode($go);
```

and use

```
echo $go;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use session_start() at the top of your script:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
```